# Django Error Webpage not appearing

Tags: python, django

Typically when I work on my localhost when editing a small application with Django http://127.0.0.1:8000/ would serve an error page when there was an error. About an hour ago something happened(I don't know what) and errors are only showing up in my terminal, but not on my webpage, such as:

```
[12/Aug/2015 03:08:51]"POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 10511
```

It used to be really nice when I got errors on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ within chrome. Anyone know how to turn this back on? DEBUG is equal to true in settings.py.

Comment: Check your DEBUG settings.

Comment: If django's debug page was appearing earlier then it's most likely due to an error further down in your pipeline that's preventing the debug page from appearing. I've run into this a few times but I don't know remember the fix off the top of my head. Could you post some code? The first files to look at are views.py, urls.py, and settings.py. Make sure to remove any content that you don't want the entire world to see (e.g. database settings).

Comment: I uninstalled Django 1.8 and installed 1.7 and everything is working now. Weird stuff.